# Can I assume that recv will read in one shot data smaller than the minimum ethernet frame size?

Tags: sockets, networking, recv

As stated [here](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Ethernet), minimum ethernet packet size is 64 bytes:

> Ethernet packets with less than the minimum 64 bytes for an Ethernet packet (header + user data + FCS) are padded to 64 bytes

Can I assume that `recv` will read in one shot data smaller than the minimum ethernet frame size? Let's say the other end of the connection sends 10 bytes of data in one shot, can I call `recv` once on my end and assume all 10 bytes is read?

Comment: LOL, no, it's a byte stream.  See Sergey.  I've seen actually delivered apps that make such assumptions and, yes, they fall over when you look at them sideways:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not assume **anything** when using `recv` on TCP socket. It may return any number from -1 (indicating an error) to 0 (indicating a closed socket) to N, where N is equal to buffer size provided to `recv`.

Assumptions about number of bytes read by `recv` are sources of constant pain and bugs.

Comment: Oh, I might haven't properly described my question, I should have mentioned that errors and peer close are checked, and the buffer used to `recv` the data is large enough(I know the other end of the socket sends exactly 10 bytes in one shot), do I still need to take the internal `recv_buffer` into account even the data I am going to `recv` is so small as **10 bytes**?

Comment: That I ask this question is because I encounter code that make that assumption from time to time, sometimes assumption is made for `send` as well, so I wonder if it is safe to make that assumption on some premise?

Comment: `send()` and `recv()` are different. Unless in non-blocking mode, or blocked but interrupted, `send()` will try to send the whole buffer. `recv()`, on the other side, will read something. You can read 10 bytes or 1 byte. No guarantee whatsoever.